# undefined method error trying to get cucumber testing of omniauth working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, cucumber, omniauth

I'm trying to get some cucumber tests of omniauth with Facebook working.

Currently I get the following error:

```
Given I am not logged in                         # features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:79
When I go to the homepage                      # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:51
And I follow "Sign in"                         # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:61
Then I should see "Facebook"                   # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:110
When I sign in with facebook                   # features/step_definitions/omniauth_steps.rb:1
  undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  (eval):2:in `click_link'
  ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:62:in `/^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"$/'
  features/users/login_with_facebook.feature:14:in `When I sign in with facebook'
Then I should be signed in                     # features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:60
```

I have the following omniauth_steps.rb file

```
Given /^I sign in with facebook$/ do
  step %{I follow "Facebook"}
end
```

And support/omniauth.rb

```
Before('@omniauth_test') do
  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
  p "OmniAuth.config.test_mode is #{OmniAuth.config.test_mode}"
  OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = {
    :provider => 'facebook',
    :uid => '1234567',
    :info => {
      :nickname => 'jbloggs',
      :email => 'joe@bloggs.com',
      :name => 'Joe Bloggs',
      :first_name => 'Joe',
      :last_name => 'Bloggs',
    },
    :credentials => {
      :token => 'ABCDEF...', # OAuth 2.0 access_token, which you may wish to store
      :expires_at => 1321747205, # when the access token expires (if it expires)
      :expires => true # if you request `offline_access` this will be false
    },
    :extra => {
      :raw_info => {
        :id => '1234567',
        :name => 'Joe Bloggs',
        :first_name => 'Joe',
        :last_name => 'Bloggs',
        :username => 'jbloggs',
        :email => 'joe@bloggs.com',
      }
    }
  }
end

After('@omniauth_test') do
  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = false
end
```

When I do manual tests, everything works, so I'm happy my configuration is ok, this is just belt and braces. The error message isn't too informative so I'm hoping that someone can stop an obvious flaw! I'm running the latest gems for rails, devise, omniauth and omniauth-facebook.

Edit

Looking at the logs, I see this in the development log:

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-22 14:52:16 +0100
  Processing by Users::SessionsController#setup as HTML
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQ<snip>IE" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-22 14:52:18 +0100
Processing by Users::SessionsController#setup as HTML
```

The test log is different, I get two 404s. The first is legit (I use a custom Omniauth setup) but the second is calling "users/auth/facebook" again instead of "/users/auth/facebook/callback"